# React Typescript fails to compile with a Generic Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

My React app is failing to compile when I start using generics with my component. Error here:

```
src/components/MyTable.tsx
  Line 50:24:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  48 | interface TableProps<T> {
  49 |   rows: Array<T>;
> 50 |   columns: Array<keyof T>;
     |                        ^
  51 |   // columns: string[];
  52 | }
  53 |

src/pages/TestPage.tsx
  Line 25:15:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  23 |   return (
  24 |     <div>
> 25 |       <MyTable<MyRow> rows={rows} columns={["id", "title"]} />
     |               ^
  26 |     </div>
  27 |   );
  28 | }
```

I get no errors in eslint or my editor. In fact, VSCode recognizes that `columns` prop should be a `<keyof T>` type which is `MyRow`. This looks like something wrong with the compiler itself.

[image]

Here is my code:

**Component File:**

```js
interface TableProps<T> {
  rows: Array<T>;
  columns: Array<keyof T>;
  // columns: string[];
}

function MyTable<T>(props: TableProps<T>) {
  const { rows } = props;

  console.log(rows);

  return <div></div>;
}

export default MyTable;
```

**Page File:**

```js
type MyRow = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
};

const rows: MyRow[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Row 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Row 2",
  },
];

function TestPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyTable<MyRow> rows={rows} columns={["id", "title"]} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestPage;
```

Any idea why its failing to compile?

**package.json file just in case it useful:**

```json
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.12"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

### Update

Fresh installs work. This is turning out to be a problem with some of the packages installed and/or the eslint configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <MyTable<MyRow> rows={rows} columns={["id", "title"]} />
```

first, remove `<MyRow>` from the above line because as long as i remember this is not valid react-typescript syntax

you are already saying make table generic over an object which you will provide in data. then see if an error happens and what are the error logs.

Comment: it is a valid syntax but it's not necessary, you have already added rows props as Array<MyRow>

Comment: That only gets rid of the one error. I can get rid of the other error by commenting out the `Array<keyof T>` type for comments and uncomment the `string[]` type version but that still doesn't solve the fact that both are valid syntax.